# Is there a way to parse the form fields of signed PDFs e.g. using Python or Java and write them to a CSV?

Tags: parsing, pdf, ocr, form-fields, pikepdf

I would like to parse form fields from signed PDF's. With this I mean for example the checkboxes. I have already tried different ways (with Python) like PyPDF2, pikepdf or even pdfminer, however I only get the letters out and not the form fields. If someone has an approach how I could parse form fields from signed PDFs it would be my salvation. I can parse the individual letters, but not the form fields. I'm already thinking about trying OCR, but it seems very complicated to me and it might be easier.

Does anyone of you have an idea how I can parse the form fields out of signed PDF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both qpdf and cpdf can extract the whole PDF as JSON. For example `cpdf -output-json in.pdf -o out.json`. This should allow you to find the form fields. You will need a little knowledge of the PDF format, though.

Comment: There is nothing in signed pdfs in general that makes a difference in retrieving Form field values. Thus, there seems to be something special about the signed pdfs you have to deal with. Can you share an example file illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

It's unclear what you want precisely.

1. You want to extract information from the form fields in the PDF
2. Your PDF is signed and then scanned, you want to extract an image of the signature

Either option is possible using `borb`

If you want to extract information of the form fields, I would recommend you look at [section 4.4](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#44-getting-the-value-of-a-formfield-in-an-existing-pdf) of the examples repository. I'll post the example here for the sake of completeness.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import HexColor
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PDF


def main():

    # open document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle)
    assert doc is not None

    # get
    print("Name: %s" % doc.get_page(0).get_form_field_value("name"))
    print("Firstname: %s" % doc.get_page(0).get_form_field_value("firstname"))
    print("Country: %s" % doc.get_page(0).get_form_field_value("country"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This example reads an input PDF, and then fetches the values of the form fields.

You can also do more low-level manipulations, `borb` represents the PDF as a JSON-like datastructure (nested arrays, dictionaries and primitives). So you can get the information relatively easily.

If you want to apply OCR to a PDF, I would recommend yet another example in the examples repository. This time in [section 7.2](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#72-performing-ocr-on-a-pdf).

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.ocr.ocr_as_optional_content_group import OCRAsOptionalContentGroup

from pathlib import Path


def main():

    # set up everything for OCR
    tesseract_data_dir: Path = Path("/home/joris/Downloads/tessdata-master/")
    assert tesseract_data_dir.exists()
    l: OCRAsOptionalContentGroup = OCRAsOptionalContentGroup(tesseract_data_dir)

    # read Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output_001.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])

    assert doc is not None

    # store Document
    with open("output_002.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Joris, thank you very much for your reply. To be exact I want to read the values from checkboxes. The challenge here is to handle signed PDFs, there are a lot of options to read unsigned PDFs and their values from checkboxes, with signed PDFs it always fails to open them. Is a signed PDF simply a scan, actually not or?



I tried to use your library, but the same result: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. What am I doing wrong, I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the PDF itself cannot be opened, then the reason is not its "signedness". Signed PDFs contain internal markers which exhibit any changes after the point of signature. This in itself otherwise does **not** prevent access.
If a PDF is **_encrypted_** (which is a different, independent thing!) then all access without a password may be impossible. PyMuPDF can detect this and will raise an appropriate exception.
Yet independently from the previous, files (not only PDF) may be protected by DRM mechanisms (Digital Rights Management). **This** may be your case, because of the weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract (but also manipulate) Form Fields with PyMuPDF - whether signed or not:

```py
import fitz # the PyMuPDF package
doc = fitz.open("your.pdf")
for page in doc:  # iterate over pages
    print()
    print(f"Form fields on page {page.number}")
    for field in page.widgets():  # iterate over form fields on the page
        print(f"field type '{field.field_type_string}', value '{field.field_value}`")
```

Comment: I Jorj, thanks for your answer. Your approach is a great way to read the field types - works with unsigned PDFs as expected. 

But with signed PDFs I get the error that Fitz does not find the file (fitz.fitz.FileNotFoundError: no such file: 'filled_test_signed.pdf'). Do you have any further idea how to extract this from signed PDFs?

Comment: @idontknowiteither - there is no difference whether signed PDF or not - you simply mis-spelled the filename  ... use "filled_test_signed.pdf" instead of "your.pdf".

Comment: I just replaced the "your.pdf" with my existing pdf "filled_test_signed.pdf". It works superb with unsigned files, e.g. my file "filled_test.pdf" prints out:
Form fields on page 5
field type 'CheckBox', value 'Ja`
field type 'CheckBox', value 'Off`
field type 'CheckBox', value 'Ja`
and so on... but whenever I assign a signed pdf I get the error that the file is not found. The way I read up is that there is really no big difference between signed and unsigned PDFs, only the encryption. Why are the signed files not found? Thank you again.